# Configure Nginx subdomains for different paths

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I want to configure subdomains, so that it can accept all subdomains except admin. Currently admin is handled by other nginx configuration.
For example,I want to have ru.example.com and en.example.com to navigate to same website without redirection,and admin.example.com to navigate another website without redirection.

Here is my configuration file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
        root /srv/www/example.com;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```